# ERROR says: "WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available"

Tags: apache2, php

on running the command `$ sudo phpenmod mbstring` 
I'm getting the error

> WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under
>   /etc/php/7.3/mods-available

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the module first:

```bsh
sudo apt install php-mbstring    # or: sudo apt install php7.3-mbstring
```